# Removing duplicate words in semicolon separated string

Tags: php, regex

I have a long string in this format:

```
hello; world; this; is; a; string; hello; of; some; words;
```

It's semicolon + space separated. I need to remove all duplicate words in the string. The resultant string should look like this (with the second `hello;` removed):

```
hello; world; this; is; a; string; of; some; words;
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: The strict definition of *regex* doesn't allow this. Some extensions (for instance for the *P* programming languages) can do this.

Comment: I think that you should have told us what you had already tried and what results you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example in PHP:

```html
$string = "hello; world; this; is; a; string; hello; of; some; words;";
$string = implode("; ", array_unique(explode("; ", $string)));
```

`string` will contain the new string: "hello; world; this; is; a; string; of; some; words;". If you want a string like this: "hello world this is a string of some words" remove `"; "` from the implode parameters

**EDIT:** as requested by vihan1086, I have posted my original code below:

```
$string = "hello; world; this; is; a; string; hello; of; some; words;";
$matches = array_unique(explode("; ", $string))
$string = implode("; ", $matches);
```

Comment: Much better to use `explode()` instead of `preg_match()`

Comment: Excellent use of the `array_unique()` function. I didn't even know such a function existed.

Comment: You're answer is a very nice  copy of *two* other answers. I would keep your original answer :)

Comment: @RandomUser Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30550955/1620622) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30550956/1620622) which is an *exact*.

Comment: @vihan1086 fair enough but it's probably worth considering that my answer came first and I only made my code shorter in the last edit (using the same functions and method)

Comment: @RandomUser The method you're using came ~15 minutes later

Answer (score 0):

I would use split on "; " (semi colon and space) then iterate through the array of words removing duplicates. Finally iterate over the array printing our "; " in between the words.

If you specify the language you are using I can provide sample code. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\w+\b)(?!.*\1\b)/g
```

The above would provide behavior close to what you want, however it would omit the first hello instead of the second hello so your resultant string would end up being `world; this; is; a; string; hello; of; some; words;`

It is worth nothing that the above regex is using capturing groups so the actual result would not be returned as the actual string unless you put it back into that string format.

Answer (score 0):

## One-liner

RegEx isn't right for this task. You can use `explode` `array_unique`  and `implode`.

```
$yourString  = implode('; ', array_unique(explode('; ', $yourString)));
```

## Alternative

If you know you might have a string without `;`  you can use:

```
$yourString = (!empty(explode('; ', $yourString))) ? (implode('; ', array_unique(explode('; ', $yourString)))) : $yourString;
```

## Tests

I ran this with some sample inputs and here's what I got:

> `hello; hello`     -> `hello`
>
> `hello; hello; hi` -> `hello; hi`
>
> `hello`            -> `hello`
>
> `hello`           -> `hello;`
>
> `hello; world; this; is; a; string; hello; of; some; words;` -> `hello; world; this; is; a; string; of; some; words;`

## Quick explanation

`explode` will split the string's `;` . `array_unique` will remove duplicates. `implode` will fuse it back together

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead of using regex:

```
$string = implode("; ", array_unique(explode("; ", $string)));
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the format of the original string? If so, it would be significantly easier if you got rid of the space after the `;` because when you explode like this, since there is no trailing space, the last entry will still have the `;` after it, so if it is duplicate it won't be removed. I would omit the space and the trailing `;` if possible. If not, I can update my answer to provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew proposed, splitting up the list would probably be the easiest solution.

```
<?php
$strWords = "hello; world; this; is; a; string; hello; of; some; words;"

// Split the words up:
$allWords = explode('; ', $strWords);

// Array to store all unique words:
$uniqueWords = array();

foreach($allWords as $word){
    if(!in_array($word, $uniqueWords, true)){
        // This is a unique word
        array_push($uniqueWords, $word);
    }
} /* end for-loop */

// Dump the array of unique words:
var_dump($uniqueWords);
?>
```